# System.BadImageFormatException when using Coherence and Moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq, oracle-coherence

When using the following line in a moq unit test, I get a System.BadImageFormatException.

```
mockDataAccessLayer.Setup(dal => dal.ListItems(It.IsAny<List<IFilter>>()));
```

The exception:

```
System.BadImageFormatException : [C:\Users\ric\AppData\Local\Temp\q3a2acu1.brz\RJ.DAL.test\assembly\dl3\cb8fb82f\e33b012a_c5f6cc01\RJ.DAL.test.DLL] The signature is incorrect.
at RJ.DAL.test.DALLayerTest.DataAccessLayerTest()
```

The full unit test:

```
[Test]
public void DataAccessLayerTest()
{   
    var mockDataAccessLayer = new Mock<IDAL>();
    mockDataAccessLayer.Setup(dal => dal.ListItems(It.IsAny<List<IFilter>>()));
    var dataAccessLayer = mockDataAccessLayer.Object;
}
```

I am fairly sure the problem lies with the List of IFilters, as I use very similar code elsewhere without the It.IsAny which works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: First google hit, exact match: http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=152

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Hans mentioned, it was due to missing an assembly for the interface. Adding the dll containing the interface fixed the problem.